# Has anyone managed to get the code generated by facebook `Comments Plugin Code Generator` to work?

Tags: html, facebook, plugins

I'm using the code generated from the Facebook code generator here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/ and as instructed I've created a HTML file with the following code in it.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v11.0" nonce="PMiduXpV"></script>
        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-width="1" data-numposts="1"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

however, nothing is displayed on the UI. I can only access the comments if I manually inspect the page and manually navigate through the loaded Iframe.
Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Where are you located, could it have something to do with the restrictions mentioned on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/ regarding EU data protection regulations?

Comment: There is also a relatively current bug report for this, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/854001531875629/

Comment: Actually, that might be it. Thanks @CBroe